# Adding Outlines to plot_ly Histogram

Tags: r, plot, histogram, analytics, plotly

I'm going through some plot_ly examples and I was surprised to see that the histogram plot does not outline the bars of the histogram.

Here is the code:

```
x.data <- 1:20

plot_ly(
  x = x.data,
  type="histogram",
  histnorm = "probability",
  nbinsx = 20
)
```

Which results in this:

[image]

I'm looking to have it display similar to this, with visible outlines:

[image]

I've looked through the documentation [here](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#histogram) but can't quite work out how to add outlines to the bars. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add bargap = 0.01 in layout to see outlines.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find out how to do this in the Python plotly lib for myself and stumbled upon [this](https://plotly.com/r/reference/histogram/#histogram-marker-line) in the docs. The line property for the histogram is under marker (for some reason?). You can set the line's colour and width from there. I'm afraid I don't know how to do this in R but hopefully the docs help!